# Pandas: Number of unique days in a timestamp Series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have Pandas DataFrame with nearly 3,000,000 rows. One of the columns is called `TIMESTAMP`, and of the datetime64 type. The timestamp format is given below:

```
2015-03-31 22:56:45.510
```

My goal is calculating the number of days data were collected. My initial approach was simple:

```
(df.TIMESTAMP.max() - df.TIMESTAMP.min()).days
```

However, it occured to me this may not be always correct, since there is no guarantee data was collected everyday. Instead, I tried counting unique days in the timestamp series using `map` and `apply`, and both take a considerable amount of time for 3,000,000 rows:

```
%timeit len(df['TIMESTAMP'].map(lambda t: t.date()).unique())
1 loops, best of 3: 41.3 s per loop

%timeit len(df['TIMESTAMP'].apply(lambda t: t.date()).unique())
1 loops, best of 3: 42.3 s per loop
```

Is there a way to speed up this computation, or an entirely different but better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: could try something like: df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('D')) then get the number of groups, not sure if it will be faster but I suspect so.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get the unique dates you should first [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) (to get the *time at midnight that day*, note this is **fast**), then use [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
In [31]: df["Time"].dt.normalize().unique()
Out[31]:
array(['2014-12-31T16:00:00.000000000-0800',
       '2015-01-01T16:00:00.000000000-0800',
       '2015-01-02T16:00:00.000000000-0800',
       '2015-01-04T16:00:00.000000000-0800',
       '2015-01-05T16:00:00.000000000-0800'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

---

Original answer (I misread question):

To get the *counts* could use [`normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) and then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
        Time
0 2015-01-01
1 2015-01-02
2 2015-01-03
3 2015-01-03
4 2015-01-05
5 2015-01-06

In [12]: df['Time'].dt.normalize().value_counts()
Out[12]:
2015-01-03    2
2015-01-06    1
2015-01-02    1
2015-01-05    1
2015-01-01    1
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

but perhaps the cleaner option is to resample (though I'm not sure if this is less efficient):

```
In [21]: pd.Series(1, df['Time']).resample("D", how="sum")
Out[21]:
Time
2015-01-01     1
2015-01-02     1
2015-01-03     2
2015-01-04   NaN
2015-01-05     1
2015-01-06     1
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks! `%timeit len(df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.normalize().unique())` gives me 281 ms, 148 times faster than the map approach!

Answer (score 1):

If your index is a DateTimeIndex, I think you can do something like this:

```
print(df.groupby(df.index.date).shape)
```

Comment: Timestamp is the date column, not the index.

Comment: Is there an advantage in keeping the index as DateTimeIndex? It is just a column for now as @AndyHayden mentioned.